# Python "Twisted" Error in Vim

Tags: vim

After installing [CoVim](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim) and running PluginInstall, I receive the following error at vim startup:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vim/bundle/CoVim/plugin/CoVimClient.vim:
line  376:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

However, I have run `pip install twisted`. What could be causing this?